# Render React component recursively

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, react-redux, nested-sets

I got an array of objects and need to recursively render every single object like unmarked list :

```
<ul>
   <li>
   </li>
</ul>
```

All data comes from server like simple JSON:

```
{
        "Id": 1,
        "Description": "asd",
        "Src": " ",
        "Lft": 0,
        "Rgt": 9
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Description": "asd2",
        "Src": " ",
        "Lft": 1,
        "Rgt": 2
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Description": "asd3",
        "Src": " ",
        "Lft": 3,
        "Rgt": 8
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "Description": "asd4",
        "Src": " ",
        "Lft": 4,
        "Rgt": 5
    },
    {
        "Id": 5,
        "Description": "asd5",
        "Src": " ",
        "Lft": 6,
        "Rgt": 7
    }
```

I am using Nested Sets model for adding and deleting. Add/delete is ok, adding new element generates and recalculate correct keys (with deleting same ok)
Also a I can just render all the items (in my case in a line). But the target is make its view hierarchical.
Here is an example how I render lft|rgt (but i am using usual JS)

[image]

To render that I use next function (**function renderItems(items**)):

```
    renderItems(items) {
    let node = document.getElementById('root');
    node.innerHTML = '';
    if (items.length) {
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        var tree = fetchChildElement(ul);
        node.appendChild(tree);
    }
    function fetchChildElement(container, lft, rgt) {
        items.filter(filterItems); //go through data array
        return container;

        function filterItems(item) {
            if (item.Lft === (lft || 0)) {
                var element = document.createElement('li');
                element.innerHTML = (item.Lft + " | " + item.Rgt);

                //check if element got nested elements, if true - call function again
                if (item.Lft + 1 < item.Rgt) {
                    var childContainer = document.createElement('ul');
                    var child = fetchChildElement(childContainer, item.Lft + 1, item.Rgt - 1);
                    element.appendChild(child);
                }

                //add element to container
                container.appendChild(element);

                //check if next element exists and call function for them
                if (rgt && item.Rgt < rgt) {
                    fetchChildElement(container, item.Rgt + 1, rgt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my components: 
**Item.js**

```
class Item extends Component {

render() {
    let { item, showModalPlusClicked, deleteItem } = this.props

    return (
        <li className="item">     
                {item.Description &&
                    <div>
                        <img src={item.Src} alt="" />
                        {"Description: " + item.Description}
                        <div className="buttons">
                            <button className="addBtn btn" onClick={(id) => showModalPlusClicked(item)}>+</button>
                            <button className="removeBtn btn" onClick={(id) => deleteItem(item.Id)}>-</button>
                        </div>
                        <p>lKey is {item.Lft} <span>|||| rKey is {item.Rgt}</span></p>
                        <p>______________________</p>
                        <p>id is {item.Id}</p>
                    </div>
                }   
        </li>

    )
}
```

}

And here is my **ItemList.js** component, where, I think all recursive magiс should be:

```
class ItemList extends Component {
render() {
        let { items, showModalPlusClicked, deleteItem } = this.props
        return ( 
            <div className='items'>
                <ul>
                    {items.map((item) =>
                        <Item
                            key={item.Id}
                            item={item}
                            src={item.Src}
                            desc={item.description}
                            lft={item.lft}
                            rgt={item.rgt}
                            showModalPlusClicked={showModalPlusClicked}
                            deleteItem={deleteItem}
                        />
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

An below there is a screenshot how it renders with correctly stylized Items (but not hierarchicaly), also used display:inline-block in li.items for better understanding
[image]

Btw, to render items like on first picture I just pass {this.renderItems(items)} to ItemList`s render() method.

So, in the end I think is better to resume of all that words above.

- I got an array of objects ItemsList.
- Every object in ItemList is Item.
- Every Item got 2 main identificators (leftKey - lft and rightKey - rgt) which are should use to display Item in unordered list ().
- I got javascript function which can get this keys and show smth in index.html but I can`t understand how to remake it (or may be function should be fully another)
- Also, I pass different data into my JS function and it renders ul>li correct, so I really think all changes should be in it.

So, the main problem that I cant get how to render my react component Item in that way.

**EDIT**
'That way' I mean - Item Components renders like unordered list (see 1st image). I that image only left and right keys, instead of them there should be whole Item component  (like on image 2)

**EDIT**
Any thoughts how to implement this? I am in despair...

Comment: What should be the output? Like on a first screen?

Comment: yes, output should be like on the first screen, but not just left and right keys (like in my case). should be react component Item.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while developing multithreaded chat application. [Demo](https://tarangdave.github.io/multithread-production/)

I designed the css of the component such that when a new component renders it shifts a little bit to achieve what you are looking for.
[React Code](https://github.com/tarangdave/multithreadchat-react/blob/master/src/components/chatroom.js)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that solution, but unfortunately it is not what actually need. Still try to render my component recursively and now I think I need to understand how to wrap component in <ul> or <li> and then add whole list to html. Debuged my js function and its ok, but problem with correct wrappin is still is.